# How to create an instance of a platform specific class in KMM?

Tags: kotlin, kmm

For example, I have the next class declarations:

```
// commonMain 
expect class MyUseCase {
    operator fun invoke()
}
// androidMain
actual class MyUseCase {
    actual operator fun invoke() {}
}
// iosMain
actual class MyUseCase {
    actual operator fun invoke() {}
}
```

Is there a way to create an instance of `MyUseCase` in `commonMain`?

```
// commonMain
val useCase = MyUseCase() // Doesn't work
```

**P.S.** It must be possible cuz **Kotlin** has information about actual implementations at the moment when it will create an instance of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a constructor for your class:

```
// commonMain 
expect class MyUseCase() {
    operator fun invoke()
}
// androidMain
actual class MyUseCase actual constructor() {
    actual operator fun invoke() {}
}
// iosMain
actual class MyUseCase actual constructor() {
    actual operator fun invoke() {}
}
```